# Why swapExactTokensForETH works and not swapExactTokensForTokens when swapping Token A to WBNB on Pancake?

Tags: python, web3py, bsc, pancakeswap

In Python using `web3.py`.

I wrote a code to swap a token:

```
A (0xc3e8F389C4ACEDB0AFe230d713136bE21D0421Ac)
```

to

```
WBNB (0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c)
```

For some reason, when I call `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`, the swap go through, but when I call `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`, with the same parameters, it does not and raise the error `TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED`.

Someone can give me an explanation please?